# How I can finish Installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I had this Problem while installing Ubuntu , I'm using Windows 8.1 and I have an empty partition 75 GB and I want to install ubuntu on it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about the red exclamation mark, please right click the *unallocated* in GParted and click *Information* to receive details about what the exclamation mark means.

Comment: It said that I should disk has no partions !! and as you can see in the top pic i didn't found any of it to complet installation !!

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: the problem with me that is i can open the  partitions and  look to files  but when  i want to complete installation as u can see in 1st pic !! cant find partition to  !

Comment: Please open *GParted*, the program in the second screenshot, right click the exclamation mark, click "Information" and tell us what the error is. Because this is probably what keeps you from creating new partitions.

Comment: i have this : http://postimg.org/image/7nauq76kh/7253b37b/

Comment: Do you have any files on the hard drive (sda)?

Comment: yes !! that's the problem i have just one parttion empty 75 GB !! but as yyou see cant use it hehe XD

Comment: I asked whether you had any files on the hard drive. When you tell me you had just one empty partition, this means **no files** (i.e. no personal documents, music, a Windows installation)? Just asking because the quick fix will make all existing files on the hard drive inaccessible.

Comment: yeah , I have ! personal documents !! i told you about empty partition because i want to install Ubuntu in it !! but I could not !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gparted won't read partition table](http://askubuntu.com/questions/600964/gparted-wont-read-partition-table). Somehow your partition table got a bit messed up, this might help you fix it.

Comment: this might help you as well: ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1038943 and ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634779

Answer (score 0):

The best way (if you ever do reinstall later) to do it is to make **2 EXT4 partitions*** out of the **unallocated space leaving 2X the amount of RAM in MB of unallocated space** which you then use to make a **linux-swap** partition. Then go into the Partition Editor and choose one of the Drives as mount point **/** and the other as mount point **/home** and select Format for the **/** one and then choose the SWAP partition and make sure it's marked as mount point **swap** in the Edit Box.

*(This means then that if you ever reinstall Linux on these drives, **you won't have to format your /home** part of the Installation (But you will have to for **'/'**!))

PS: You may want to try making a **NEW PARTITION TABLE** on /dev/sda1 (Be warned: It completely wipes the HDD clean of partitions!), it's in the Device menu of GParted under 'Create Partition Table' (And it's also there on the bottom-right hand corner of the Installer).

Comment: "The best way" according to whom?

Comment: the problem is that I already have partitions ! and one of  is empty 75 gb !! and is full !!  and I'm trying you use Ubuntu and Win 8.1  dual boot  !!

Comment: Wait, on that, it just has an unallocated space on the list, no Win8.1, though is 8.1 on sda1 or 2 according to GParted?

Comment: ...And also can you Alt+PrtScr the window that appears when you right-click the ! Space and press Information on the appearing menu in GParted? That might help us a lot more.

Comment: i upload the image here   : http://postimg.org/image/7nauq76kh/

Comment: Hang on, this might help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1038943 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634779

Comment: yes Big problem !! so if per exmple i will install ubuntu 12.01  , i can upgrad  it to 14 .10 ??

Comment: Yes, the non-graphical way of doing it is 'sudo do-release-upgrade' in Terminal whilst the more user friendly way is to use the Updater and then upgrade when your shown to the prompt of 'Ubuntu 14.04 is available, you have 12.04' (Oh and BTW: If you don't know the way Ubuntu Versions are numbered is Year Released (.) Month Released)